# Context of function after used with Meteor.bindEnvironment?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have problem with this code recently:

```
function doSth() {
  console.log(this);
}

const fWithMeteorEnv = Meteor.bindEnvironment(doSth);

fWithMeteorEnv.call({});  // expect to see a plain object in console
```

What I expect is to see a plain object in console but not, it is something else. It seems that `Meteor.bindEnvironment` prevents the returned function to be called with another context. Are there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you're trying to achieve is not possible, i.e. you will need to bind your context at the moment you're calling `Meteor.bindEnvironment`. You can do it with `.bind()`, e.g.

```
const fWithMeteorEnv = Meteor.bindEnvironment(doSth.bind(context));
```

or you can pass the context as the third argument to `Meteor.bindEnvironemnt()`, e.g.

```
const fWithMeteorEnv = Meteor.bindEnvironment(doSth, null, context);
```

The second argument is an exception callback.

Answer (score 2):

`Meteor.bindEnvironment(func, onException, _this)` accepts 3 arguments and the function it returns is bound to the third argument. You need to bind it at the time it is created and using `apply` or `call` on it will pass the arguments, **but the `this` reference will be overridden**.

```
function doSth() {
  console.log(this.foo);
}

const fWithMeteorEnv = Meteor.bindEnvironment(doSth, null, {foo: 'foo'});

fWithMeteorEnv.call({foo: 'bar'}); // will print 'foo'
```

This is rather similar to what you should expect with [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). You should not expect to `call` a bound function and have its `this` context to be your argument.

```
let f = function() {
  console.log(this);
}.bind({foo:'foo'});

f.call({foo: 'bar'}); // will log `{foo: 'foo'}`.
```

---

If you really need to set the `this` context for some function, you can wrap it and pass it as a parameter to the wrapper function instead (e.g, use the first argument to the wrapper as the `this` context of the original function).

If you need to have both the `call` semantics of the returned function, this **can be done** in a rather convoluted way.

```
/**
 * Wraps the function.
 * When the returned function is called, it sets the wrapped function's `this` to its first
 * argument and passes it the rest of its arguments.
 */
function _wrapToMakeCallable(fn) {
  return function() {
    var _this = Array.prototype.shift.apply(arguments);
    fn.apply(_this, arguments);
  }
}

/**
 * This function wraps the boundWithEnvironment function and maps the arguments such
 * that it can be `call`ed or `apply`-ed as normal, using `wrapper`.
 */
function callableWrapAsync(fn) {
  const bound = Meteor.bindEnvironment(_wrapToMakeCallable(fn));
  return function() {
    Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0, 0, this);
    bound.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}

function doSth() {
  console.log(this.foo);
}

Meteor.startup(function() {
  const fWithMeteorEnv = Meteor.bindEnvironment(doSth, null, {foo: 'foo'});

  fWithMeteorEnv.call({foo:'bar'}); // will print 'foo'

  const callable = callableWrapAsync(doSth);

  callable.call({foo:'bar'}); // will print 'bar'
});
```